# How is this MOSFET being controlled? (LTC2954 PushButton On/Off Controller)

Tags: mosfet

[In the datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/2954fb.pdf) for this pushbutton controller we are given a typical application circuit:

[image]

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how this circuit is switching this MOSFET on or off to allow current into Vin on the drain side.

From my (weak) understanding of the datasheet, when /PB is pressed, /EN goes LOW, and it will stay low until a long press to flip it HIGH again. But how does this low signal turn on the MOSFET to allow current into Vin on the drain side of the MOSFET? The gate being wired to the source through  a 100k resistor is also a bit of a mystery to me, as well as how the MOSFET here seems to be oriented to allow current from source to drain.

Edit: Want to also point out. That looks to be a P-MOSFET which may explain much of my confusion.

Comment: Yes it is a PMOSFET, so pulling the gate to ground turns it on. The 100k resistor is is a pull up to make sure the FET is in a known state if the gate is left floating.

Comment: Actually it looks like the EN pin is driven as open drain, so you NEED that pull up resistor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the MOSFET is oriented to allow current from source to drain. It is necessary if you want to use it as a switch that can be controlled by the gate voltage:

[image: source-to-drain]

If it is connected otherwise (the drain to a battery, the source to a DC controller Vin), you cannot control the switch, because it is bypassed by PFET's body diode -- the diode shown in your TYPICAL APPLICATION drawing (it is not shown in the LTspice circuit, but it is implied that the body diode exists, with the anode connected to the PFET drain and the cathode connected to the PFET source):

[image: drain-to-source]

In this configuration, the DC controller Vin is connected to the battery via the body diode, even when the PFET is off.

The gate is wired to the source through two 100k resistors. The left one (in your circuit), connected to the battery, provides a pullup for a presumably open-drain EN output of the LTC2964-2 controller. The 100K resistor connected to the gate slows down the rise time of the drain. It is necessary for startup, to provide time for controller voltages to settle and be ready to control the switching operations. See what happens if we short-circuit this resistor:

[image: no-gate-resistor]

The time constant fell to the value defined by the internal resistance of LTC2964-2's EN output, which may be insufficient for startup delays.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to accept the other answer since it's very thorough.But the simple answer to what I was making a mistake on is that the MOSFET is of P-Type which will usually require a negative Vgs to turn it on. I also found that the 100k resistor between gate and source can be adjusted to ensure Vgs is within operating range for the datasheet of the MOSFET. Could have some other use as others have pointed out.

[Falstad Simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgB3ENPcQqlHl5h%20UTnyoiB%20CWIBuIPFWKFZKqBpqSUGqjATilso7hpiug4aOyEre8VoEozjkKbEAnCmB1TvO7DQNMHhxBB9ZOl9RSDYAc0UqdxMg%20wTwgKCMtxtdNi9Xd0LbYPhYhLAaMxthKto4PIVK6pKeNxK9et1daAMAM3rpXlc-bHodGEgUBwa21xRnc3a7ZfBBJZq14ZEtpZodn23VP1iuKMjA8DrT2kvmtzwze5vsR6vqt5P87iFZS25FpIyuJ-gsXLNAWwAM5qY6iE4aPoAQwANlCGIZlKojF8LDJNsVeLEgA)

Change the voltage source towards the bottom from 0 to 12V and vice versa to simulate the MOSFET turning on or off.

Comment: You are right, the primary purpose of the pullup 100K resistor is to set an operation point to guarantee the correct switching operation. The other 100K resistor that connects EN to gate has a zero or negligible effect on the operation point for a PMOSFET without ESD protection, because the gate-oxide leakage current is below 100nA. If the transistor has internal ESD protecting diodes, gate-to-source leakage current is in the range of microamps and so participates in the gate bias voltage divider. AON7407 of my example circuit has no ESD protection.